# Correct way to use !is_null()

Tags: php

There is an example in PHP Object-Oriented Solutions that seems to be flawed, if I understand is_null properly.

The sample code in the book is as follows:

```
if (!is_null($required) && !is_array($required)) {
throw new Exception('The names of required fields must be an array, even if only one field is required.');
}
```

This code is supposed to test that a var $required is not NULL and is an array.  To my understanding, is_null() returns TRUE if the variable is not set or is NULL.  So, does it make sense to negate is_null() in that example if you're trying to throw an exception when the variable is not set, NULL, or is not an array?  The only way an exception is thrown is if (true && true) is satisfied.

Comment: The code is testing if $required is not an array, not if the variable is null. It's doing the is_null check to make sure it can call is_array on it.

Comment: @Kyle Why would `is_array` *not* return true/false (well, really just false) if NULL is supplied as an argument?

Comment: the is_null test is not even needed here. http://3v4l.org/LqqdC

Comment: @Calimero it is being used to make sure $required is set, though it seems odd to not use isset().

Comment: @Dave : Sorry, no it doesn't. is_null() may serve two purposes here and is cumbersome in both : either $required is not set, and a notice will be thrown anyway, either the variable is set to null and is_array() would have done the job on its own. Please read the answers & comments below for details.

Comment: @Dave From my understanding, isset is not used because isset will return TRUE even if the $required variable had a empty string, a string with a space, or an empty array().

Answer (score 3):

FROM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php

> A variable is considered to be null if:
>
> it has been assigned the constant NULL.
>
> it has not been set to any value yet.
>
> it has been unset().

```
<?php
if(is_null($obj)){
    echo 'is null';
}
```

While `$obj` is considered NULL because it hasn't been registered yet, it will still throw a `Notice: undefined ...`

The correct use for your `if` statement should first check to see if the variable exists then check to see if it is an array.

`if (!isset($required) || !is_array($required)) {}`

-or-

`if (empty($required) || !is_array($required)) {}`

The nice thing about `is_array()` is the fact that if `$required` IS NULL then it's not an array and will pass the if clause.

`isset()` and `empty()` will both ensure that the variable exists. Failure to pass either of these methods will quit the if statement and no errors will be returned.

Comment: Yes, that's NULL/is_null. But, *why* is `is_null` "required" before `is_array`?

Comment: it's not required. the correct use would be `isset()` to ensure that the variable exists, then checking that the variable is an array. you will always receive an error if the variable doesn't exists, which is why you use `isset()`

Comment: You don't even have to use isset. Just typehint the function parameter as optional. `function foo($bar = null){}`.

Comment: @Calimero If the variable in question was being passed as a function argument: yes.

Comment: @Samuel : since we're talking OOP programming here, function context would be a safe assumption :) We're in complete agreement otherwise. (I've just discovered 3v4l.org won't display notices no matter what, that explains the other thread).

Comment: @Calimero *Why* are we talking about "OOP" when there is *no* relevant "OOP" involved in the code samples? I agree completely about using function parameters - or rather, *never* accessing a variable before it is definitely assigned - but those don't dictate a need to bring in something else.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all the feedback, but somehow I think part of my question was not addressed.  The fact that the variable is being tested with a Logical AND, means that both statements must be TRUE for the Exception in the if clause to run.

But, I don't think the use of !is_null($required) is correct.  The sample code from the book was testing for a variable to contain an array with one to many values.  Even if it has one value, the $required variable (for other reasons) still must be declared as an array with a single value.  So, if $required hold's a value of (int) 5, an Exception should be thrown. If the $required variable is not declared/instantiated, an Exception should be thrown.  If the $required variable holds NULL, an Exception should be thrown.  Here is where the logic of this sample code fails.  Using the online php command line that @Calimero posted, this logic fails when $required is set to NULL.

Instead of using !is_null($required) , is_null($required) without the negation should have been used since is_null returns TRUE if the value of $required is indeed NULL.  So, if you negate is_null() when the $required value happens to be NULL, that part of the logical AND operation becomes FALSE, therefore the Exception never gets run at all because the logical AND operation requires both statements to be TRUE for the logic to jump into the curly braces.  Which is precisely what the if clause was supposed to catch in the first place. The sample code was supposed to catch the $required variable not being set and not being of an array type.

And as I mentioned in a comment, isset() probably wasn't used because isset will return TRUE even if the $required variable is an empty string, a string with a space, an empty array, etc.

Someone please confirm I'm not talking stupid.  LOL.

Take a look at this: (http://3v4l.org/QpVXq)

Comment: The original logic also does not throw an Exception when the $required variable is an empty array(). This happens because is_array() finds an empty array as TRUE, but the negation of !is_array($required) flips it to FALSE.  The logical AND will never allow the Exception to be thrown as you need both statements to evaluate to TRUE.

Comment: You're right. In this case, as @Samuel Cook explained, it all depends on the context the given code is in. If you have reason to think $required may not exist, then isset() should have been used instead of is_null() as it protects from a php notice. In all other cases, the condition (or the Exception message itself) is flawed somehow as you explained, thus my initial statement that is_null() should probably be removed either way.

Comment: @Calimero , thanks for reassuring me that I wasn't losing my mind.  Following an example in a book sometimes makes you 2nd guess yourself when something doesn't seem right.  My thoughts exactly on removing is_null.  This should have been handled differently than what the original code states.  I'm still on the fence with the use of isset in this scenario.  But, there's many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

****Is_null****
The is_null is php construct language and  can be used to test whether a variable is set to null.

```
   $myVariable = null;
    is_null($myVariable); // this returns true,because it is set to null

$myVariable = 10;
is_null($myVariable); // this returns false, cuz it is assigned to value


If the variable does not exist is_null will also return true, 
but with an error notice as it is not supposed
 to be used with uninitialized variables.

 //returns true and also notice with (undefined variable notice) 

    is_null($myNewVariable);// true (undefined variable notice)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code is part of a function, it could be that the function allows for null values, but if the value is passed and it's not an array, then an exception must be thrown. If the code is not part of a function, it may be just demonstrating how to detect if a value is an array only if it isn't null, thus allowing null values.