# Check if model property is set (when null)

Tags: php, laravel

Say I have a model called `Fruit` which can have a `null` value for `seeds`. The `seeds` column exists in the database table.

The problem is that using `isset` is returning false for this model property when it is set to `null`, or maybe it has something to do with the __magic stuff in general? So how do I check if the model has the property `seeds` even when it is set to `null` or declared via magic?

For example:

```
$fruit = Fruit::find(1);

if (isset($fruit->seeds)) {
  echo 'Yes';
}
else {
  echo 'No';
}
```

This will echo `No` if the value of `seeds` is set to `null` in the database.

Comment: Add the condition is_null($fruit->seeds).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to use !is\_null()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292730/correct-way-to-use-is-null)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `is_null()`:

```
if (isset($fruit->seeds) && !is_null($fruit->seeds)) {
```